# Random triangles are appearing in Blender 2.81

Tags: mesh

Random triangles are appearing and disappearing and i can't figure out why, this happens with any complex model I create or import, anyone has any idea?
My drivers are updated, this only happens in Blender 2.81, Blender 2.80 works fine, even 3ds max works fine.

[image: weird glitches]

Comment: Can't tell if those are relationship lines or real geometry, can you provide a .blend?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/jndw6vqutn3ha3r/MeshProblem.blend/file

Here is the blend file, play the animation and watch the vertices go crazy, if the problem does not happen for you, then i can assume it's my PC's fault.

Comment: Animation runs until frame 48, all looking fine here Edit: I'm using the latest Buildbot build

Comment: Thats weird, then its my pc that cant handle 2.81 for some reason